# Require.js: "file not loading" in AMD process

Tags: requirejs, jsfiddle

I use the Require.js "AMN" to load my files, this is my HTML file.

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" href="js/require.js"></script>
```

when i load my main.js - i made this config to load my jquery file.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        "jQuery":'lib/jquery-1.9.1.min'
    }
});

require(['jQuery'], function ($) {
    console.log($);
})
```

But i am not getting any console. all my paths are correct.[image: my js folder's structure]

my index.html file located at the parent of the js filder.

Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery module for AMD should always be lowercase. Check what path is used when browser requesting files using developer tools in chrome or fiddler. This way you will know if you configured it right.

UPDATE: please correct the syntax for loading script. Must be src instead of href.

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: I check with chrome netwrok tab, i didn't see any files that loading.. apart from css file i didn't see anything.

Comment: By the way i think you don't need to include .js extension for the data-main attribute.

Comment: Oh I see error in your script, it's not "href" it should be "src" attribute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29344/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-tomas-kirda)